# Serializing object into a flat Dictionary<string,string>

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, serialization

Given a class

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyInnerClass Property1 {get;set;}
    public MyInnerClass2 Field1
    public MyInnnerClass[] Property2 {get;set;}
}
```

I need a serializer, not unlike MVC serializer to serialize the above into the following dictionary.

```
new {
        {
            "Property1.InnerField", "1",
        },
        {
            "Field1.InnerProperty", "7/7/2007"
        },
        {
            "Property2[0].InnerProperty", "0"
        },
        {
            "Property2[1].InnerProperty", "1"
        }
}
```

Basically it needs location, and native value, or recurse further until it finds a non-reference type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talking about your question we may put the answer the didactic way and just exclude any existent serialization architecture. That way you would be totally free to walk into the objects reference tree with no efforts using Reflection and populate the result dictionary.

We need a simple method to visit a given object, then for each public property recursively call itself. The signature should include a string to say wich is the current parent chain (eg.: `"Property1.InnerProperty4.InnerProperty7"`) and the return type should be a `Dictionary<string,string>` with just the stuff coming from the current and nested objects.
At the beginning it should check if the argument is of value type or not and in the former case just create a new dictionary, add a new KeyValuePair(parent+name,value) and return; while in the latter case, create a new Dictionary, then foreach public property call itself passing the current property, the parent+name string and join the returned dictionary with the previously created one and return this big dictionary at the end of the loop. We may add another condition at the beginning checking if the passed object implements something like IEnumerable interface. In that case instead of just looping through its members, loop through its indexer and call the method for each item.

I found time to implement what I described yesterday. Here you have a recursive method designed to return a dictionary of (public property fullnames)-(value) pairs of a given object. Of course it may not be EXACTLY in details what you want to achieve but you'll find lots of trick, ideas and concepts to compose your own:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class ClassA {
        int p1 = 1;
        string p2 = "abcdef"; 
        List<string> p3 = new List<string>() { "ghi","lmn" };
        ClassB p4 = new ClassB();
        ClassB p5 = null;

        public int PA1 { get { return p1; } }
        public string PA2 { get { return p2; } }
        public List<string> PA3 { get { return p3; } }
        public ClassB PA4 { get { return p4; } }
        public ClassB PA5 { get { return p5; } }
    }

    public class ClassB{
        private string p1 = "zeta";
        public string PB1 { get { return p1; } }
    }

    public class Program {

        public void Main()
        {
            ClassA o = new ClassA();
            Dictionary<string, string> result = GetPropertiesDeepRecursive(o, "[o]", new List<string>() { "MyNamespace" });
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a dictionary of propertyFullname-value pairs of the given object (and deep recursively for its public properties)
        /// note: it's object oriented (on purpose) and NOT type oriented! so it will just return values of not null object trees
        /// <param name="includedNamespaces">a list of full namespaces for whose types you want to deep search in the tree</param>
        /// </summary>        
        public Dictionary<string, string> GetPropertiesDeepRecursive(object o, string memberChain, List<string> includedNamespaces)
        {

            List<string> types_to_exclude_by_design = new List<string>() { "System.string", "System.String" };

            //the results bag
            Dictionary<string, string> r = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            //if o is null just return value = [null]
            if (o == null)
            {
                r.Add(memberChain, "[null]");
                return r;
            }

            //the current object argument type
            Type type = o.GetType();

            //reserve a special treatment for specific types by design (like string -that's a list of chars and you don't want to iterate on its items)
            if (types_to_exclude_by_design.Contains(type.FullName))
            {
                r.Add(memberChain, o.ToString());
                return r;
            }

            //if the type implements the IEnumerable interface...
            bool isEnumerable =
                type
                .GetInterfaces()
                .Any(t => t == typeof(System.Collections.IEnumerable));
            if (isEnumerable)
            {
                int i_item = 0;
                //loop through the collection using the enumerator strategy and collect all items in the result bag
                //note: if the collection is empty it will not return anything about its existence,
                //      because the method is supposed to catch value items not the list itself                
                foreach (object item in (System.Collections.IEnumerable)o)
                {
                    string itemInnerMember = string.Format("{0}[{1}]", memberChain, i_item++);
                    r = r.Concat(GetPropertiesDeepRecursive(item, itemInnerMember, includedNamespaces)).ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.Value);
                }
                return r;
            }

            //here you need a strategy to exclude types you don't want to inspect deeper like int,string and so on
            //in those cases the method will just return the value using the specific object.ToString() implementation
            //now we are using a condition to include some specific types on deeper inspection and exclude all the rest
            if (!includedNamespaces.Contains(type.Namespace))
            {
                r.Add(memberChain, o.ToString());
                return r;
            }

            //otherwise go deeper in the object tree...            
            //and foreach object public property collect each value
            PropertyInfo[] pList = type.GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo p in pList)
            {
                object innerObject = p.GetValue(o, null);
                string innerMember = string.Format("{0}.{1}", memberChain, p.Name);
                r = r.Concat(GetPropertiesDeepRecursive(innerObject, innerMember, includedNamespaces)).ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.Value);
            }
            return r;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Diego, that's all right. I did this before, but I lost that code. Somewhere in MVC library someone must have implemented this. I wanna just grab and reuse that if possible. So yeah I'm just asking if there's a solution available somewhere in the great big internet already written. I can re-implement it no problem, but a little pressed on time.

Comment: Oh man you really shouldn't have. I was expecting someone to point me to an MVC class library not build from scratch. But this is above and beyond that - much much appreciated.